# How do I unlink Google accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management

I accidentally linked two of my google accounts, so when I log into one it logs me into both. I cannot seem to find a way to undo this. How do I separate them again?

Comment: To unlink  Google account,Go to settings ->Accounts and Import ->Grant access to your account in the primary account.Now chose the delete option to unlink the linked account.

Answer (score 2):

From [Sign in to multiple accounts at once - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en)

> ## Signing out
>
> When you sign out of any account, you’ll be signed out of all your accounts on that browser. If you want to use multiple sign-in
> again, follow the steps in the “Add your Google Accounts” section
> above again.
> **To sign out of all accounts:**
>
> 1. Go to your [Google Account page](https://accounts.google.com/).
> 2. Click your profile photo or email address at the top right of the page.
> 3. Click **Sign out** from the drop-down menu.